# Trying to auto load these packages in Clojure files, they worked the first time but don't work anymore

Tags: debugging, clojure

I have the following function to auto start raindow-delimters and paredit

```lisp
(defun my-lisp-hook ()
  (enable-paredit-mode 1)
  (rainbow-delimiters-mode 1))

(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook 'my-lisp-hook)
```

It worked at first but subsequently it stopped and I am not sure why

If I manually run them they start but then stop working again all of a sudden.

Here is my entire `.emacs` with a different config and still rainbowdelimeters does not work, and haven't tried paredit-mode in this config

```
(require 'package)
;; (add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)
;; Comment/uncomment this line to enable MELPA Stable if desired.  See `package-archive-priorities`
;; and `package-pinned-packages`. Most users will not need or want to do this.
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(package-selected-packages '(rainbow-delimiters ace-window paredit cider clojure-mode))
 '(tab-width 4))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x o") 'ace-window)

(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook 'rainbow-delimiters-mode)
```

Comment: Please don't just post your entire init file and ask others to debug it. *Bisect it, to find the culprit part*, and post only that. Show a step-by-step recipe with minimal code to repro the problem, starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file).

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalled Emacs used this config instead is working now

```lisp
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
;; Comment/uncomment this line to enable MELPA Stable if desired.  See `package-archive-priorities`                                                                                                               
;; and `package-pinned-packages`. Most users will not need or want to do this.                                                                                                                                    
;;(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/") t)                                                                                                                      
(package-initialize)
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.                                                                                                                                                                     
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.                                                                                                                                                  
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.                                                                                                                                                         
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.                                                                                                                                                             
 '(package-selected-packages
   '(paredit rainbow-delimiters clojure-mode-extra-font-locking cider)))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.                                                                                                                                                                         
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.                                                                                                                                                  
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.                                                                                                                                                         
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.                                                                                                                                                             
 )

(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook 'rainbow-delimiters-mode)

(add-hook 'cider-repl-mode-hook #'enable-paredit-mode)
(add-hook 'cider-mode-hook #'enable-paredit-mode)
(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook #'enable-paredit-mode)
```